# i want to create a document with array field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In mongodb schema i just want to add an array in this schema but have some problem when I insert data , all time return an error string "This library (validator.js) validates strings only"

In Model:

```
let prescriptionSchema = new Schema({

    appointment_id: {
        required: [true, 'Appointment id is required'],
        type :Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Appointments'
    },
    remarks: {
        type: String,
    },
    diagnosis_description:{ type : Array , "default" : [] },
    diagnosis: [{ 
        diagnosis_description: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }],
    investigation: [{ 
        test_name: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        test_description: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }],
    medicine: [{ 
        medicine_name: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        medicine_dosage: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        medicine_power: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }]
}, 

{timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
}});
```

In controller i just write a console log , so i thing problem is in mongodb , mongo can't understand then array, please help.....

```
In postman :
{
    "appointment_id": "5d3ab1a4590ad324b2abdb76",
    "remarks" : "Next checkup after one month",
    "diagnosis":[
        {
            "diagnosis_description": "Fiver"
        }
    ],
    "investigation":[
        {
            "test_name" : "Blood",
            "test_description" : "Dengu"
        },
        {
            "test_name" : "Blood",
            "test_description" : "HIV"
        }
    ],
    "medicine":[
        {
            "medicine_name":"Paracetamol",
            "medicine_dosage":"650",
            "medicine_power":"AM"
        }
    ]
}
```

const path          = require('path'),
    router          = require('express').Router(),
    dir             = `${path.dirname(__dirname)}/controllers`,
    helperLib       = require(path.resolve('./config/lib/helper_lib'));

This is routes :

```
let ReadDirectory   = new helperLib.read_directory.readDirectory();
let Middleware      = new helperLib.middleware();

//@ require all controllers for this module
let fileObj         = ReadDirectory.requireFiles(dir);


//@ routes mapping
router
    .put('/addprescription', fileObj['prescription.account'].addprescription);
    //.get('/prescriptionlist', fileObj['prescription.account'].prescriptionlist)
    //.put('/updateprescription', Middleware.decodeToken, fileObj['prescription.account'].updateprescription);


module.exports = {
    router: router,
    base: '/api/prescription'
};
```

Comment: Please post the code for the creation route.

Comment: {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "status": "failed",
    "message": "This library (validator.js) validates strings only"
}

this is the postman responce

Comment: The code. I mean the express route.

Comment: In controller  i just do a console.log

Comment: please check once i add my routes

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code that is responsible for using validator.js package. The error which occurs is saying that you're probably trying to use validate function from this library which takes only string parameter.

> This library validates and sanitizes strings only.

Link: [validator.js package usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)